# How to disable the Software Update dialog box from appearing on the desktop in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: update-manager

What configuration changes can I make in my system to disable the Software Updater dialog box from popping up?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open the tool "Software and Updates"
- On the "Software" tab, set "Automatically check for updates" to "Never".

From that point, the dialog will not anymore appear. You can at any time run the "Software Updater" tool to have the system check for and install updates at a time you decide.

To change the setting using the terminal, set both `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists` and `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade` to `"0"` in the system configuration file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`.

Comment: Which file should I modify if I want to use the command to achieve the above effect?

Comment: I have added the information to the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much!